# Why am I getting an error for this?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, initwithstyle

Why am I getting these errors?
[alt text http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/2203/help.tif](http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/2203/help.tif)

It says:

> Error: Request for member "jokeTableView" in something not a struction or union

What does that mean? And why is it breaking. I tried reading about [initWithStyle](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewController/initWithStyle:) but I just could catch up on it

Here is my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


 @interface TableViewController : UITableViewController {

NSMutableArray *jokes;
IBOutlet UITableView *jokeTableView; 


 } 

 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *jokes;

 @end
```

Thanks!

Comment: The way you access it assumes that jokeTableView is a property of TableViewController.

Comment: Maybe you could try copy/paste just the actual code, small picture is not much use :) Just a cut out of the line in question and maybe relevant lines from header file.

Comment: maybe it doesn't like your Jokes? (Sorry couldn't resist) :-)

Comment: @lothar lol its ok. If I were you, I wouldn't be able to resist that either :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your object (TableViewController) has no property named jokeTableView.

In order to access jokeTableView with the special dot operator, it needs to be a property. Otherwise you have to access it using Key-Value-Coding compliant methods or directly using the -> operator (or just use it as an ivar and no reference to self):

```
jokeTableView.delegate = self;
```

or

```
self->jokeTableView.delegate = self;
```

or

```
[self jokeTableView].delegate = self;
```

or

```
@property (retain) UITableView *jokeTableView;
// later...
self.jokeTableView.delegate = self;
```

Also note, however, that you are setting an outlet in the initializer and this won't work. You'll have to set this in the -[TableViewController awakeFromNib] method since self->jokeTableView will be nil when the initializer is actually called (which happens in IB prior to serializing the object into the nib file).

Comment: Hey jason. lol this has to be about the 3rd time you've helped me this week! thanks man!

Ok I added my header file... The thing is, I DO state what jokeTableView is...

Comment: Why do you want me to change it to "self.jokeTableView.delegate = self;" if it was already that?

Comment: And I initialized jokeTableView in awakeFromNib, but now the take view is just blank... It doesn't even display the rows...

Comment: The point of his fourth option is that if you want your current (property) syntax to work you could actually declare it as a propert--as the line just above it shows.

Comment: Oh ok i get it. But then why after I did that, and I initialized with AwakeFromNib, did my tableView not show up?

Comment: If this view is in a nib, why not just set the delegate property there? Isn't UITableView's delegate property an outlet?

Comment: well it is already a delegate... But thats what apples code said to do.. Should I not do that?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing this at init time, the outlets should be NULL, so this initialization shouldn't do anything.  This should be done at awakeFromNib time at the earliest.